# Redux state returns undefined, after state update

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, state

I am changing the state of an array of objects on a button click action.
when I click on the button it changes the state and throws undefined for one of the console.log statements which I will mention below in the code. And when I click the button again it displays the following error

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
at stockReducer (stockReducer.js:28)**

This is my action code where I am getting am setting the data. Ideally ill be doing it from backend later on.

```
export const getStockAction = () => {
    return (dispatch) => {

        dispatch({ type: GET_STOCK_LOAD, payload: 'Loading...' })
        
        var stockData = [{ productID: 1, stock: 1 }, { productID: 2, stock: 1 }, { productID: 3, stock: 1 }, { productID: 4, stock: 1 }, { productID: 5, stock: 1 }, { productID: 6, stock: 1 }, { productID: 7, stock: 1 }]

        dispatch({ type: GET_STOCK_FETCH, payload: stockData })
        
    };
};
```

another action code for updating the state.

```
export const setStockAction = (toggleID) => {
    return (dispatch) => {

        dispatch({ type: SET_STOCK_LOAD, payload: 'Loading...' })
        
        dispatch({ type: SET_STOCK_FETCH, payload: [{ toggleData: 0, toggleID }] })
        
    };
};
```

Reducer

```
import { GET_STOCK_LOAD, GET_STOCK_FETCH, SET_STOCK_LOAD, SET_STOCK_FETCH } from "../actions/stockActions";

const initialState = {
    getStockIsLoading: false,
    getStock: [],
    setStockIsLoading: false,
}

const stockReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case GET_STOCK_LOAD:
            return {
                ...state,
                getStockIsLoading: true
            }
        case GET_STOCK_FETCH:
            return {
                ...state,
                getStock: action.payload
            }
        case SET_STOCK_LOAD:
            return {
                ...state,
                setStockIsLoading: true
            }
        case SET_STOCK_FETCH:
            return state.getStock.map(product => {
                if (product.productID === parseInt(action.payload[0].toggleID)) {
                    return { ...product, stock: product.stock = parseInt(action.payload[0].toggleData) }
                }   
                return product
            })
        default: return state
    }
}

export default stockReducer
```

The page from where I am calling the actions from and my click event to update the state

```
const Product = ({ match, getStockData, setStock, getStock }) => {

console.log(getStockData) //the statement which throws undefined after buttonclick 

  var params = match.params

  useEffect(() => {       
    getStock()
  }, [])

const handleTestToggle = (toggleID) => {
    setStock(toggleID)
  }

return (
    <div>
                <Grid container justify="space-between" className={classes.newSection}>
                  <Grid item>
                    <Button onClick={() => handleTestToggle(params.productID)} variant="outlined" color="secondary" >
                      {getStockData && getStockData[params.productID - 1].stock === 1 ? 'available' : 'Unavailable'}
                    </Button>
                  </Grid>
  
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    getStockData: state.stock.getStock
  }
}

const mapDispatchToPtops = dispatch => {
  return {
    getStock: () => dispatch(getStockAction()),
    setStock: (data) => dispatch(setStockAction(data)),
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToPtops)(Product)
```

How am I not able to update the state back and forth after click ?
it updates only once when I click button after that if I click it throws above undefined error for the state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning only the array, but you need to return the whole new state:

```
case SET_STOCK_FETCH:
  const newGetStock = state.getStock.map(product => {
                if (product.productID === parseInt(action.payload[0].toggleID)) {
                    return { ...product, stock: product.stock = parseInt(action.payload[0].toggleData) }
                }   
                return product
            });
  return {
    ...state,
    getStock: newGetStock,
  }
```

Comment: oh yes, I totally neglected it.
thank you very much